# How to use FDT with Aptana together on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, aptana, fdt

I'm new to Eclipse. Just downloaded trial of FDT and trying to get it all work together. So things i did:
1) Downloaded and installed(unpacked) Eclipse (i'm on Mac)
2) Installed FDT 3.5 Beta as Eclipse plugin
3) Installed latest AptanaStudio

Now, when I start the Eclipse, I cannot create Flash Project anymore. Seems that Aptana has replaced the FDT menus and actions. My aim - is to make Eclipse create a flash projects where I can edit PHP/HTML/JS files with highlighting, and also I would like the ability to work with MySQL. So my problem is now - lack of knowledge - what to do now? How can I create such a Flash Project with PHP files?

Thanks in Advance.

P.S. I've seen that some of the users use that combo( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385169/best-ide-for-actionscript-3-coding) ), therefore decided to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try again with the latest [FDT 3.5 release](http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/developer-tools/fdt-3/whats-new/), it should work now!